# Is there a way to Git pull a specific file from a different branch to my branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-checkout, git-fetch

Hi there I'd like to know if there's a way to pull specific file from a different branch to my branch and at the same time compare/know what's got added to my file.

I've tried this method `git checkout -m origin/branch <yourfilepath>` it seems my `index.html` basically just swap from the my team mates `index.html` and doesn't have the code added from my team mates `index.html` to mine. And lastly I've tried using `git pull origin branch` atleast using `git pull` I could see whats added from my `index.html`(`git fetch` + `git merge` = `git pull` basically what I understand from `git pull` I could be wrong) but problem is it doesn't pull specific file it has to pull the entire branch.

I'd love to know your thoughts about this topic if there's another way to pull specific file. Thank you in advance

Comment: try `git merge-file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much support for merging individual files in git.  You can use `git merge-file`, but first you need three copies of your file:

- your version
- your teammate's version
- a "base version" that shows what the file looked like before either set of changes was made

So for example, based on what you've written perhaps the current state looks like this:

```
... O -- A <--(origin/branch)
     \
      B <--(branch)
```

where `A` contains your teammate's version and `B` (currently checked out on `branch`) contains your version.  Then you could do something like

```
git checkout origin/branch -- yourfilename
mv yourfilename yourfilename.theirs
git checkout $(git merge-base branch origin/branch) -- yourfilename
mv yourfilename yourfilename.base
git checkout HEAD -- yourfilename
git merge-file yourfilename yourfilename.base yourfilename.theirs
```

You might want to keep the .base and .theirs files around for a bit, while you examine the result (especially if there are conflicts); but you probably want to clean them up when you're done

```
rm yourfile.base yourfile.theirs
```

Also, a word of caution:  Be careful with the `-m` option to `checkout`; it means somewhat different things depending on which form of `checkout` you use.  In this case it doesn't mean what you want (and in those cases where it means something like what you want, it can cause staged changes to be lost).

Comment: Hi sir I forgot to add that what I'm suppose to merge is that the index.html from my teammate into my index.html my apologies sir what I'm really aiming is that changes from my teammate's index.html should added to my index.html basically a git pull

Comment: I aslo got an error mv: 'index.html' and 'index.html' are the same file

Comment: Yes, this is a procedure to merge your teammate's version of a file into your version; that could be index.html or anything else.  I understand why you think it's a pull, but git does not pull files.
The error suggests that either you mis-entered one of the `mv` commands, or you're using an OS that only allows one dot in a filename.  I can't think of a modern system that only allows one dot, but if that's it you may have to use names like `index.base` and `index.theirs` as the temporary names for those files.